# Not able to install bz2 in Python 3

Tags: python, linux, centos7, python-3.7

I am not able to install the bz2 package in Python 3 Can please anyone guide

I followed the below commands

sudo yum install bzip2-devel

after that, I start my python 3.7 terminal and use the below command

```py
import bz2
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/sysopt/lib/python3.7/bz2.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Comment: There should be no need to install it; it is part of Python's standard library.

Comment: @tripleee Only if it's compiled in, which it always necessarily isn't.

Comment: How did you install Python 3.7? If you installed it by hand from source, you will need to redo that after you've installed the bzip2 development libraries, as you've done.

Comment: @tripleee Yes it is for standard lib but in python 3.7 it is not working

Comment: @AKX Means I have to install python 3.7 again , Am I right, or it can be solved by creating virtual env

Comment: @AVIRALBHARDWAJ Yes, you will need to reinstall Python 3.7. Virtualenvs will not help; they will inherit the builtin libraries (which bz2 would be) from the non-virtual interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and the `/usr/local/sysopt` path, I assume you've installed Python 3.7 from a source package.

When you did that, the Python `configure` script checked whether it has the bits to compile the `bz2` module, and as you didn't have `bzip2-devel` installed during that time, the builtin `bz2` module didn't get compiled.

You will need to recompile and reinstall Python 3.7 to get it included. At that point, you may also want to pay heed to any other optional modules that inadvertently don't get installed; `sqlite3` tends to usually be one that ends up missing!

Comment: Is there any way we can include missing packages ?

Comment: For builtin modules, not after Python has been compiled.